# Eclipse Plugin only contains manifest

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-pde

I am attempting to develop an Eclipse plugin. The plugin runs from inside Eclipse (i.e. when I launch a test instance of Eclipse with my plugin from inside Eclipse, I can use the plugin in the test instance.)

However, when I attempt to generate a plugin that could be installed by other systems using File > Expoort > Deployable Plug-ins and fragments, the zip file created, contains a single jar file which itself contains only a manifest file:

```
$ jar tvf com.foo.bar_1.0.0.d.jar
     0 Wed Feb 10 12:14:12 EST 2016 META-INF/
   863 Wed Feb 10 12:14:10 EST 2016 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

For example, it does not include my icons or my plugin.xml file.

I am not (yet) using maven-tycho or any other extra-Eclipse means of building the plugin.

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must list everything you want in the plugin in the `build.properties` file, so check that file. When you run from within Eclipse this file is not checked for accuracy but it must be correct when you export.

For a simple plugin it might look something like:

```
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml,\
               OSGI-INF/
source.. = src/
```

This is including the 'META-INF' folder, the 'bin' folder (where your class files are), the 'plugin.xml' file and the 'OSGI-INF' folder.

In the plugin.xml editor use the 'Build' tab to set the contents of this file.